# Create Content Types that create other node for fields

Tags: views

I would like to create a content type, say for example *Podcast*, that would have other pages for some of the fields.

A `field_audio` that is a *file* would automatically generate a `/node_url/audio` page, a `field_transcript` that is a *Longtext* would be `/node_url/transcript etc.

My initial hypothesis is to use a views page to set the path but I am really confused with the interface and how best to solve this problem.

`EDIT`

In order to clarify, I'll go step-by-step for the desired functionality.

A content type is configured to publish at `domain.tld/podcast/podcast-title`. This content type has a lot of fields that are removed from the display using Display Suite.

What I would like to do is to use URLs that automatically generate displaying content based URL parameters, similar to how Drupal tags do but for individual nodes.

Example website:
`http://codepen.io/inkovic/pen/qEXJpo` is the original content.
`http://codepen.io/inkovic/pen/qEXJpo.css` is the css
`http://codepen.io/inkovic/pen/qEXJpo.html`is the HTML and so forth.

I could do this manually with a contextual view + block on the actual node-url, but 
`Views -> Contextual Filter -> Content: Nid -> Content ID form URL` would break if the url is different from the actual node.

So `podcast/podcast-name/transcript` would render a view based on the **podcast-name** part of the URL.

I do not want to create a custom content type of transcript, mp3, links etc and use Entity Relationship because that would ruin the content authoring experience.

Comment: I am not fully clear about your requirement but this link may helps you https://www.drupal.org/node/1066712 https://www.drupal.org/node/458316

Comment: I'll edit my question but no, this isn't what I'm looking for.

I want to create a path that renders content without creating a new node and referencing it.

Comment: if i am not wrong you want to display a page which contain all the audio field data present in POdcast content type.

Comment: No, I want to render a contextual view but since I want the URL to be different the typical Nid -> Content ID from URL doesn't work.

Comment: "Content ID form URL" should works with Path Alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to make a new node - just to show field value on separate page. Use Views module to accomplish that.

1. Create new View based on Content with Page display (path node/%/test_field).
2. Set Contextual Filter to Node NID (and make it global with "All display" option). Provide default value: Content ID from URL.
3. Choose field you want but remember to set "This page (override)" option.
4. Create as many page displays as you want with new path (based on the same rule - node/%/some_name) and select another field (under Fields)

That is how it should looks like:
[image]

[EDIT]
Install [Sub-pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto) module for second level path aliases.

Comment: Thank you, this does work, but only for `node/%/path` format. For vanity urls I learned I needed the [Views Path Arguments](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_url_path_arguments) module.

Comment: It works as I wrote but you need one more module. Instead of Views Path Arguments try [Sub-pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/subpathauto). It is really easy to use and works not only with views.

Comment: Oh, awesome. Thanks, that's a way more elegant solution.